# Grepl (R) function similar usage in Python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to write the following code in Python, that I already wrote in R. This is very simple however I am very new in Python. I am assigning *text* column as 1 into *pos_d* column if any of the words (from the wordlist) exist in the *df$text*. Any help would be appreciated.

```
wordlist<-list("word1|word2")
df$pos_d <- grepl(wordlist, df$text)
df$pos_d [df$pos_d == "true"] <- 1
```

Comment: You should include the Python code as well, so we know which type/data structure you are using in Python.

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you sure that is working in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

if wordlist is a list

```
df['pos_d'][(df['text'].isin(wordlist)] = 1
```

if wordlist is a string

```
df['pos_d'][(df['text'] in (wordlist)] = 1
```

Enjoy and keep posting!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using `re` and `str.contains`:

```
import re
boolean_mask_rows = df['text'].astype(str).str.contains(wordlist, regex = True, case = False)
df.loc[boolean_mask_rows, 'pos_d'] = 1
```

Above,

In first line, we are getting boolean vector based on matching string in wordlist with 'text' column in df.

In second line, we writing 1 using boolean vector indexing with `loc`.